# Kendall Correlation P-Value

Tags: r, correlation

I want to test correlation for 9 different columns using kendall and extract p-value
for correlation between v9 and 7 other columns (v2 until v8).

```html
Date  v1  v2  v3  v4  v5  v6  v7   v8
1 2014-01-05 39 4 84 75 41 6 83 610
2 2014-01-12 40 6 86 77 44 6 84 765
3 2014-01-19 39 5 82 73 40 6 81 713
4 2014-01-26 37 5 100 71 39 6 90 685
5 2014-02-02 39 5 83 70 37 5 79 601
6 2014-02-09 44 6 82 78 40 6 78 535
```

```
AllData <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(16075, 16082, 16089, 16096, 
16103, 16110, 16117, 16124, 16131, 16138, 16145, 16152, 16159, 
16166, 16173, 16180, 16187, 16194, 16201, 16208, 16215, 16222, 
16229, 16236, 16243, 16250, 16257, 16264, 16271, 16278, 16285, 
16292, 16299, 16306, 16313, 16320, 16327, 16334, 16341, 16348, 
16355, 16362, 16369, 16376, 16383, 16390, 16397, 16404, 16411, 
16418, 16425, 16432, 16439, 16446, 16453, 16460, 16467, 16474, 
16481, 16488, 16495, 16502, 16509, 16516, 16523, 16530, 16537, 
16544, 16551, 16558, 16565, 16572, 16579, 16586, 16593, 16600, 
16607, 16614, 16621, 16628, 16635, 16642, 16649, 16656, 16663, 
16670, 16677, 16684, 16691, 16698, 16705, 16712, 16719, 16726, 
16733, 16740, 16747, 16754, 16761, 16768, 16775, 16782, 16789, 
16796, 16803, 16810, 16817, 16824, 16831, 16838, 16845, 16852, 
16859, 16866, 16873, 16880, 16887, 16894, 16901, 16908, 16915, 
16922, 16929, 16936, 16943, 16950, 16957, 16964, 16971, 16978, 
16985, 16992, 16999, 17006, 17013, 17020, 17027, 17034, 17041, 
17048, 17055, 17062, 17069, 17076, 17083, 17090, 17097, 17104, 
17111, 17118, 17125, 17132, 17139, 17146, 17153, 17160, 17167, 
17174, 17181, 17188, 17195, 17202, 17209, 17216, 17223, 17230, 
17237, 17244, 17251, 17258, 17265, 17272, 17279, 17286, 17293, 
17300, 17307, 17314, 17321, 17328, 17335, 17342, 17349, 17356, 
17363, 17370, 17377, 17384, 17391, 17398, 17405, 17412, 17419, 
17426, 17433, 17440, 17447, 17454, 17461, 17468, 17475, 17482, 
17489, 17496, 17503, 17510, 17517, 17524, 17531, 17538, 17545, 
17552, 17559, 17566, 17573, 17580, 17587, 17594, 17601, 17608, 
17615, 17622, 17629, 17636, 17643, 17650, 17657, 17664, 17671, 
17678, 17685, 17692, 17699, 17706, 17713, 17720, 17727, 17734, 
17741, 17748, 17755, 17762, 17769, 17776, 17783, 17790, 17797, 
17804, 17811, 17818, 17825, 17832, 17839, 17846, 17853, 17860, 
17867, 17874, 17881, 17888, 17895, 17902, 17909, 17916, 17923, 
17930, 17937, 17944, 17951, 17958, 17965, 17972, 17979, 17986, 
17993, 18000, 18007, 18014, 18021, 18028, 18035, 18042, 18049, 
18056, 18063, 18070, 18077, 18084, 18091, 18098, 18105, 18112, 
18119, 18126, 18133, 18140, 18147, 18154, 18161, 18168, 18175, 
18182, 18189, 18196, 18203, 18210, 18217, 18224, 18231, 18238, 
18245, 18252, 18259, 18266, 18273, 18280, 18287, 18294, 18301, 
18308, 18315), class = "Date"), v1 = c(39L, 40L, 39L, 37L, 
39L, 44L, 41L, 40L, 35L, 39L, 35L, 32L, 36L, 34L, 32L, 34L, 32L, 
34L, 32L, 30L, 36L, 34L, 35L, 32L, 35L, 32L, 33L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 
35L, 36L, 41L, 36L, 34L, 32L, 33L, 30L, 33L, 36L, 34L, 39L, 36L, 
34L, 35L, 40L, 46L, 40L, 41L, 44L, 48L, 45L, 32L, 28L, 31L, 29L, 
32L, 31L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 31L, 28L, 30L, 29L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 
26L, 24L, 24L, 26L, 25L, 28L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 35L, 36L, 32L, 
31L, 32L, 32L, 35L, 36L, 33L, 30L, 32L, 37L, 42L, 36L, 36L, 33L, 
33L, 31L, 46L, 49L, 63L, 77L, 56L, 58L, 57L, 71L, 44L, 36L, 39L, 
35L, 35L, 35L, 32L, 33L, 36L, 33L, 33L, 34L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 28L, 
27L, 31L, 29L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 100L, 64L, 42L, 48L, 43L, 39L, 
36L, 33L, 30L, 32L, 31L, 34L, 34L, 31L, 35L, 35L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
39L, 38L, 50L, 46L, 48L, 47L, 40L, 43L, 43L, 44L, 60L, 54L, 50L, 
51L, 61L, 55L, 55L, 62L, 51L, 54L, 51L, 45L, 45L, 46L, 45L, 48L, 
47L, 44L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 54L, 53L, 48L, 51L, 47L, 45L, 
45L, 47L, 49L, 51L, 44L, 43L, 46L, 42L, 46L, 44L, 100L, 62L, 
54L, 53L, 45L, 93L, 61L, 76L, 60L, 52L, 53L, 62L, 56L, 54L, 21L, 
19L, 21L, 21L, 20L, 82L, 100L, 62L, 38L, 34L, 31L, 35L, 27L, 
23L, 21L, 21L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 20L, 19L, 20L, 19L, 21L, 
20L, 20L, 19L, 21L, 21L, 20L, 18L, 22L, 19L, 18L, 18L, 17L, 20L, 
19L, 20L, 21L, 24L, 26L, 25L, 32L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 28L, 27L, 25L, 
53L, 53L, 49L, 50L, 49L, 52L, 53L, 58L, 53L, 56L, 52L, 50L, 49L, 
52L, 62L, 46L, 45L, 52L, 41L, 45L, 50L, 48L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 50L, 
47L, 49L, 44L, 54L, 100L, 67L, 58L, 45L, 60L, 51L, 56L, 50L, 
50L, 48L, 48L, 49L, 48L, 54L, 57L, 67L, 74L, 58L, 60L, 64L, 77L, 
70L, 82L, 72L, 77L, 74L, 67L, 79L, 74L, 88L), v2 = c(4L, 
6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 
4L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 
4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 
5L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 
5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 
7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 
8L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 10L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 
8L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
9L, 6L, 9L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 
6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 5L, 9L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 
7L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 
10L, 10L, 9L), v3 = c(84L, 86L, 82L, 100L, 83L, 82L, 
76L, 74L, 81L, 72L, 67L, 66L, 67L, 64L, 67L, 61L, 67L, 63L, 59L, 
60L, 57L, 54L, 60L, 59L, 53L, 61L, 61L, 57L, 59L, 63L, 60L, 56L, 
60L, 64L, 57L, 55L, 58L, 61L, 56L, 63L, 65L, 63L, 59L, 64L, 60L, 
62L, 70L, 65L, 65L, 61L, 71L, 69L, 54L, 59L, 54L, 55L, 55L, 56L, 
74L, 100L, 86L, 69L, 54L, 55L, 48L, 47L, 48L, 48L, 46L, 44L, 
42L, 45L, 43L, 48L, 46L, 43L, 45L, 44L, 52L, 47L, 50L, 49L, 47L, 
47L, 50L, 49L, 51L, 47L, 45L, 45L, 49L, 53L, 55L, 56L, 52L, 52L, 
51L, 64L, 67L, 73L, 78L, 65L, 76L, 74L, 62L, 57L, 52L, 75L, 54L, 
47L, 52L, 52L, 49L, 42L, 45L, 43L, 45L, 42L, 44L, 41L, 40L, 38L, 
39L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 39L, 60L, 50L, 49L, 52L, 51L, 46L, 47L, 42L, 
44L, 45L, 44L, 47L, 44L, 49L, 43L, 50L, 47L, 48L, 52L, 53L, 51L, 
64L, 57L, 60L, 52L, 45L, 48L, 49L, 56L, 81L, 71L, 61L, 68L, 69L, 
67L, 69L, 61L, 68L, 69L, 63L, 63L, 61L, 59L, 78L, 60L, 56L, 57L, 
57L, 54L, 52L, 48L, 53L, 49L, 50L, 53L, 58L, 55L, 61L, 52L, 57L, 
55L, 57L, 51L, 51L, 52L, 54L, 58L, 58L, 80L, 67L, 62L, 60L, 60L, 
65L, 64L, 78L, 70L, 63L, 68L, 67L, 75L, 66L, 27L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 
24L, 30L, 35L, 33L, 31L, 28L, 28L, 30L, 28L, 26L, 23L, 22L, 21L, 
22L, 21L, 20L, 22L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 20L, 24L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 
22L, 24L, 25L, 20L, 22L, 23L, 22L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 33L, 28L, 25L, 28L, 27L, 29L, 30L, 58L, 57L, 60L, 58L, 
56L, 60L, 59L, 57L, 56L, 60L, 55L, 55L, 54L, 50L, 53L, 55L, 48L, 
50L, 53L, 47L, 46L, 51L, 52L, 55L, 61L, 60L, 51L, 51L, 57L, 53L, 
71L, 67L, 58L, 56L, 93L, 71L, 66L, 68L, 60L, 62L, 61L, 56L, 57L, 
61L, 64L, 64L, 75L, 65L, 64L, 69L, 78L, 84L, 100L, 91L, 94L, 
86L, 83L, 89L, 89L, 87L), v4 = c(75L, 77L, 73L, 71L, 70L, 
78L, 76L, 72L, 71L, 72L, 75L, 75L, 70L, 74L, 72L, 74L, 74L, 73L, 
69L, 74L, 72L, 71L, 74L, 72L, 72L, 82L, 74L, 83L, 78L, 73L, 73L, 
80L, 88L, 88L, 74L, 68L, 70L, 76L, 72L, 76L, 75L, 76L, 71L, 77L, 
96L, 85L, 100L, 90L, 81L, 80L, 87L, 86L, 81L, 77L, 81L, 74L, 
73L, 74L, 76L, 71L, 84L, 79L, 74L, 74L, 72L, 80L, 72L, 73L, 70L, 
69L, 69L, 77L, 72L, 77L, 72L, 77L, 77L, 85L, 77L, 74L, 77L, 77L, 
76L, 77L, 75L, 77L, 79L, 73L, 71L, 73L, 78L, 78L, 76L, 74L, 74L, 
75L, 81L, 86L, 95L, 91L, 85L, 83L, 90L, 92L, 72L, 67L, 72L, 77L, 
68L, 64L, 68L, 73L, 75L, 71L, 71L, 70L, 69L, 72L, 68L, 67L, 65L, 
65L, 63L, 64L, 64L, 67L, 64L, 80L, 73L, 70L, 100L, 73L, 78L, 
62L, 63L, 66L, 60L, 61L, 61L, 62L, 61L, 73L, 71L, 70L, 69L, 67L, 
67L, 68L, 64L, 73L, 75L, 70L, 67L, 64L, 68L, 76L, 71L, 73L, 75L, 
71L, 74L, 68L, 68L, 72L, 71L, 70L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 71L, 73L, 73L, 
68L, 71L, 68L, 64L, 65L, 73L, 66L, 67L, 69L, 72L, 80L, 66L, 69L, 
68L, 66L, 72L, 67L, 75L, 75L, 69L, 70L, 68L, 69L, 83L, 70L, 70L, 
71L, 73L, 76L, 77L, 82L, 74L, 71L, 70L, 71L, 77L, 71L, 66L, 65L, 
74L, 68L, 66L, 79L, 82L, 79L, 71L, 73L, 75L, 79L, 80L, 76L, 71L, 
70L, 74L, 70L, 72L, 75L, 71L, 71L, 70L, 74L, 72L, 83L, 68L, 71L, 
82L, 79L, 72L, 70L, 67L, 66L, 66L, 65L, 68L, 68L, 65L, 63L, 65L, 
68L, 73L, 69L, 74L, 77L, 68L, 67L, 65L, 67L, 72L, 74L, 75L, 74L, 
76L, 73L, 72L, 73L, 77L, 75L, 71L, 73L, 73L, 71L, 72L, 74L, 70L, 
66L, 72L, 72L, 70L, 67L, 69L, 69L, 75L, 73L, 75L, 83L, 71L, 69L, 
66L, 66L, 79L, 74L, 67L, 64L, 68L, 70L, 67L, 68L, 73L, 70L, 73L, 
72L, 69L, 77L, 77L, 76L, 82L, 77L, 73L, 71L, 79L, 84L, 84L, 74L, 
76L, 72L, 73L, 76L, 75L, 73L), v5 = c(41L, 44L, 40L, 39L, 
37L, 40L, 40L, 42L, 39L, 37L, 39L, 37L, 36L, 34L, 34L, 35L, 35L, 
32L, 33L, 33L, 32L, 32L, 31L, 30L, 32L, 32L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 34L, 
33L, 34L, 35L, 44L, 36L, 39L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 32L, 34L, 36L, 36L, 
35L, 36L, 36L, 44L, 39L, 38L, 42L, 44L, 44L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 
37L, 37L, 39L, 38L, 39L, 36L, 35L, 34L, 33L, 32L, 28L, 31L, 29L, 
27L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 29L, 29L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 30L, 32L, 35L, 32L, 
32L, 34L, 32L, 33L, 33L, 32L, 31L, 30L, 33L, 37L, 32L, 33L, 32L, 
32L, 34L, 41L, 45L, 48L, 56L, 47L, 52L, 51L, 44L, 35L, 34L, 34L, 
33L, 30L, 32L, 31L, 31L, 30L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 27L, 26L, 26L, 24L, 
24L, 24L, 25L, 23L, 25L, 25L, 41L, 35L, 28L, 32L, 31L, 32L, 29L, 
29L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 26L, 24L, 24L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 
29L, 32L, 31L, 37L, 33L, 31L, 30L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 30L, 30L, 29L, 
31L, 31L, 31L, 32L, 30L, 30L, 29L, 28L, 28L, 27L, 27L, 26L, 27L, 
25L, 27L, 24L, 23L, 23L, 25L, 25L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 25L, 24L, 25L, 
26L, 25L, 26L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 23L, 25L, 25L, 37L, 29L, 28L, 29L, 
27L, 33L, 33L, 38L, 33L, 31L, 31L, 32L, 35L, 31L, 28L, 28L, 30L, 
29L, 29L, 34L, 43L, 42L, 37L, 34L, 32L, 36L, 31L, 29L, 28L, 27L, 
28L, 26L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 23L, 25L, 26L, 
26L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 22L, 25L, 25L, 
26L, 28L, 28L, 34L, 30L, 28L, 29L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 33L, 32L, 32L, 
34L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 34L, 33L, 35L, 34L, 32L, 31L, 29L, 30L, 28L, 
28L, 28L, 28L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 28L, 29L, 28L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 
27L, 37L, 32L, 31L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 34L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
29L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 39L, 33L, 32L, 34L, 37L, 40L, 37L, 36L, 38L, 
38L, 36L, 38L, 38L, 39L), v6 = c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 
6L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 
6L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
6L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 
6L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 10L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 
6L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 10L, 
8L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 6L), v7 = c(83L, 
84L, 81L, 90L, 79L, 78L, 78L, 81L, 78L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 75L, 77L, 
79L, 82L, 85L, 81L, 80L, 81L, 81L, 82L, 85L, 80L, 77L, 82L, 83L, 
76L, 73L, 74L, 78L, 73L, 77L, 74L, 72L, 70L, 72L, 73L, 70L, 70L, 
72L, 75L, 74L, 73L, 73L, 77L, 82L, 81L, 79L, 82L, 86L, 86L, 85L, 
79L, 79L, 77L, 76L, 75L, 75L, 78L, 78L, 77L, 74L, 72L, 68L, 69L, 
72L, 69L, 72L, 71L, 71L, 72L, 69L, 69L, 72L, 71L, 70L, 72L, 75L, 
73L, 74L, 72L, 74L, 75L, 71L, 71L, 73L, 72L, 71L, 70L, 72L, 73L, 
72L, 75L, 76L, 76L, 75L, 80L, 83L, 100L, 95L, 84L, 84L, 89L, 
76L, 69L, 68L, 67L, 66L, 64L, 67L, 69L, 64L, 63L, 63L, 67L, 66L, 
65L, 69L, 64L, 62L, 62L, 63L, 63L, 60L, 63L, 66L, 69L, 64L, 67L, 
68L, 63L, 64L, 63L, 61L, 61L, 57L, 64L, 61L, 68L, 65L, 74L, 67L, 
66L, 67L, 73L, 69L, 68L, 64L, 68L, 72L, 73L, 69L, 72L, 75L, 80L, 
94L, 83L, 81L, 79L, 76L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 74L, 72L, 69L, 70L, 78L, 
78L, 81L, 76L, 75L, 76L, 75L, 73L, 74L, 73L, 73L, 72L, 75L, 72L, 
76L, 70L, 71L, 70L, 71L, 70L, 69L, 66L, 66L, 63L, 70L, 68L, 68L, 
79L, 72L, 75L, 78L, 75L, 75L, 77L, 79L, 82L, 85L, 82L, 83L, 87L, 
100L, 89L, 86L, 81L, 84L, 78L, 83L, 92L, 100L, 90L, 87L, 81L, 
82L, 79L, 79L, 79L, 81L, 79L, 79L, 76L, 78L, 74L, 73L, 68L, 73L, 
71L, 73L, 71L, 72L, 69L, 73L, 70L, 71L, 69L, 73L, 70L, 70L, 73L, 
73L, 73L, 69L, 73L, 74L, 76L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 79L, 81L, 78L, 82L, 
81L, 94L, 100L, 93L, 91L, 88L, 86L, 90L, 83L, 82L, 82L, 81L, 
81L, 82L, 84L, 82L, 81L, 80L, 82L, 81L, 81L, 80L, 78L, 77L, 75L, 
72L, 75L, 72L, 73L, 75L, 73L, 75L, 83L, 78L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 75L, 
78L, 80L, 77L, 73L, 79L, 79L, 76L, 88L, 91L, 90L, 80L, 82L, 82L, 
82L, 85L, 99L, 100L, 97L, 91L, 89L, 82L, 85L, 82L, 83L), v8 = c(610L, 
765L, 713L, 685L, 601L, 535L, 582L, 568L, 502L, 608L, 653L, 672L, 
694L, 697L, 715L, 751L, 675L, 706L, 777L, 787L, 876L, 823L, 754L, 
782L, 834L, 907L, 890L, 913L, 921L, 977L, 890L, 947L, 996L, 830L, 
974L, 921L, 912L, 907L, 871L, 805L, 876L, 909L, 861L, 865L, 901L, 
742L, 726L, 720L, 803L, 796L, 857L, 902L, 751L, 806L, 859L, 798L, 
714L, 728L, 688L, 728L, 785L, 1166L, 1105L, 935L, 1037L, 1016L, 
1037L, 932L, 1013L, 996L, 1016L, 1064L, 1104L, 1003L, 1051L, 
913L, 944L, 1044L, 1018L, 1073L, 1109L, 1055L, 1076L, 1008L, 
1016L, 996L, 1050L, 1030L, 969L, 1011L, 932L, 890L, 978L, 1008L, 
928L, 1006L, 927L, 913L, 905L, 952L, 957L, 978L, 978L, 1044L, 
1341L, 966L, 881L, 1052L, 981L, 864L, 927L, 887L, 943L, 1055L, 
1010L, 1012L, 1059L, 913L, 1028L, 1060L, 1046L, 1061L, 1043L, 
1027L, 1094L, 1065L, 1070L, 1000L, 1079L, 1114L, 1156L, 1069L, 
1157L, 1234L, 1217L, 1216L, 1190L, 1208L, 1253L, 1182L, 1133L, 
1046L, 1122L, 1013L, 1185L, 1208L, 1177L, 1227L, 1080L, 1197L, 
1123L, 1260L, 1101L, 1139L, 1054L, 1222L, 1262L, 1158L, 1241L, 
1190L, 1087L, 1155L, 1122L, 1159L, 1044L, 999L, 993L, 1193L, 
1229L, 1217L, 1301L, 1239L, 1179L, 1092L, 1226L, 1211L, 1236L, 
1327L, 1133L, 1149L, 1198L, 1158L, 1312L, 1183L, 1165L, 1163L, 
1226L, 1136L, 1130L, 1129L, 1092L, 1039L, 1019L, 1196L, 1155L, 
1169L, 1130L, 1185L, 1166L, 1174L, 1048L, 1083L, 1048L, 1161L, 
997L, 1041L, 1123L, 895L, 1034L, 1095L, 1080L, 1223L, 1074L, 
954L, 948L, 1011L, 982L, 1013L, 1078L, 1080L, 1055L, 1131L, 1145L, 
999L, 1213L, 1192L, 1144L, 1082L, 1137L, 1150L, 1104L, 1059L, 
1039L, 1099L, 1202L, 1092L, 1072L, 1126L, 1086L, 1098L, 1131L, 
1071L, 1122L, 1061L, 988L, 1043L, 760L, 1073L, 950L, 1001L, 960L, 
1034L, 919L, 922L, 944L, 996L, 970L, 996L, 996L, 1058L, 1235L, 
964L, 1043L, 979L, 865L, 1012L, 906L, 987L, 925L, 847L, 1012L, 
1011L, 1065L, 987L, 1078L, 1025L, 1010L, 1045L, 981L, 987L, 1125L, 
1184L, 1070L, 995L, 1139L, 1205L, 1286L, 1180L, 1210L, 1147L, 
1221L, 1112L, 1151L, 1117L, 1097L, 1066L, 1059L, 1050L, 1040L, 
976L, 992L, 979L, 949L, 954L, 932L, 873L, 1015L, 982L, 982L, 
1010L, 897L, 1056L, 1217L, 977L, 986L, 1004L, 906L, 890L, 877L, 
894L, 672L)), row.names = c(NA, -321L), class = "data.frame")
```

```
x <- AllData[2:9]
y <- AllData[2:9]
correlationcoef <- data.frame(cor(x,y,method="kendall"))
```

I used the above code to run the data but it only gives me the correlation coefficient, 
not the p-value that I needed. I also need to store this value into one data frame so
that I will be able to evaluate all correlations in one go.

Comment: Try ```cor.test(x, y, method="kendall")``` to get the p-values.

Comment: i want to do this for other variables as well so i thought that this should be under the loop function? and want to extract the p value instead of having to save it manually

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One could use a loop, but another approach to getting the p-values of the kendall correlation test is to use the `rstatix` package to create a correlation matrix and a corresponding p-value matrix:

```
library(rstatix)

# sample data
AllData <- data.frame(
  Date = c("2014-01-05", "2014-01-12","2014-01-19", "2014-01-26","2014-02-02", "2014-02-09"),
  v1 = c(39,40,39,37,39,44),
  v2 = c(4,6,5,5,5,6),
  v3 = c(84,86,82,100,83,82),
  v4 = c(75,77,73,71,70,78),
  v5 = c(41,44,40,39,37,40),
  v6 = c(6,6,6,6,5,6),
  v7 = c(83,84,81,90,79,78),
  v8 = c(610,765,713,685,601,535)
)

# get the correlation matrix
corMatrix <- AllData %>% cor_mat(v1:v8, method = "kendall")
corMatrix

# get the p.values
corMatrix_p <- corMatrix %>% cor_get_pval()
corMatrix_p
```

And you can specify the variables you want to include in the matrix with the `vars`argument:

> cor_mat(data, ..., vars = NULL, method = "pearson",   alternative =
>   "two.sided", conf.level = 0.95)

Just set `vars` equal to a character vector of the variable names. In other words, you could also do this:

```
corMatrix <- AllData %>% cor_mat(c("v1","v2","v3","v4","v5","v6","v7","v8"), method = "kendall")
corMatrix

# get the p.values
corMatrix_p <- corMatrix %>% cor_get_pval()
corMatrix_p
```

Comment: I tried to plot a correlogram using the code, but it won't work. Do you have any suggestions on how doing so?
`cor_plot(corMatrix,method="color",
         type="full")`
using it for the moment, but I need to add x and y axis label, edit the font size, and also add title for the graph. I already try to use corrplot as well but it wont work. Your help is appreciated @xilliam

Comment: @aua I am not familiar with the rstatix cor_plot function, but my quick read of the ```?cor_plot``` help file suggests it may not have all the functionality you are seeking. So my suggestion is to either post a new question on SO that details you new interest, or try using the ```corrplot``` package, which appears to have more options for customization.